# What are the primary and secondary flight controls for the SEPECAT Jaguar?

Tags: aerodynamics, flight-controls

What lift augmentation devices are used in [the SEPECAT Jaguar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SEPECAT_Jaguar)? I couldn't find any information.

Answer (score 1):

According to  [airvectors.net](http://www.airvectors.net/avjag.html), the flight controls of the SEPECAT Jaguar are:

> The Jaguar A had a high-mounted wing with a sweep of 40 degrees and an anhedral droop of 3 degrees, with relatively small wing area for a smoother ride at low altitude. There was a **leading-edge flap along the outboard section of each wing**, and large, **double slotted trailing edge flaps on both the outboard and inboard sections of each wing**. There was a "dogtooth" between the outboard and inboard sections of the wing.
>
> There were **no ailerons, roll control being provided by a two-section spoiler on top of each wing**, just forward of the outboard flaps. There was a prominent "fence" between the inboard and outboard sections of the wing. Along with a **conventional tail assembly, with all-moving one-piece tailplanes**, there were two ventral fins. There were **twin hydraulically-operated perforated airbrakes** ahead of the ventral fins, under the wings. The hydraulic system was dual-redundant.

(Emphasis mine)

The omission of ailerons from a ground attack fighter might seem odd, as one might presume this makes the plane less  maneuverable. But, as described in the first sentence of the quote, the Jaguars main mission was to (or at least it often had mission critical sections with) flying fast and low, which often translates into a very choppy ride. This was mitigated by the use of a smaller wing = higher wing loading. To achieve low enough approach and landing speed with such a small wing, efficient and large flaps were needed. As sufficient and consistent roll control is somewhat hard to achieve with flaperons (or at least it was when Jaguar was designed), the Jaguar had to make do with full span flaps and use spoilers for roll control.

Answer (score 0):

[image: 1]

Looks like there is a dog-tooth leading edge and no slats, with flaps at the inboard trailing edge.

Edit: Notice how the stabilator tailplane is trimmed, as well as the ailerons.